# Phone skin: round corners and a camera are small compared to the emulated phone screen, how to make them fit?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I downloaded skin of galaxy A52 from official samsung website: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/galaxy-a.html.
Moved the file into the right directory, added the device: size 6.5 and resolution 1080x2400 and API is 31. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JIPsZpIJzE.

My question is: I have those corners and a camera too small, how do I resize them to fit naturally?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change that you need to locate to the "Device frame skin definition" folder that you downloaded and pasted before. For me that was this folder:

> C:\Program-Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\resources\device-art-resources\Galaxy_A52

You should open "layout" file and see how different frames are set. In my situation I found that fore_port.png was at the forefront. I checked and it had dimensions 324x720. Dimensions of the screen are 1080x2400 so you should google "change dimensions of png" and change them. Then, replace the file. After this, restart android studio and everything works.

Now I have something that looks like this: [image]